# How to interpret Causalforest's CATE and confidence intervals after fitting model?

Tags: python, econometrics, causality

I am working on a causal model using EconMl and this article as a starting point: https://towardsdatascience.com/causal-machine-learning-for-econometrics-causal-forests-5ab3aec825a7.

In the visualization below (at the end of this article), a CATE confidence interval is shown to showcase the model performance. However, I am not able to interpret how to read it and what it really means. I get that we want the interveral to be as narrow as possible but my questions are:

- Given the nature of not having ground truth (my understanding is we are computing counter-factuals), how can we measure performance in first place? Am I misunderstanding something here?
- As far as the chart goes, does this mean that the more observations we include, the more unreliable the CI of our treatment effect (CATE) becomes? How is this intuitive? In the ML world, typically more samples add reliability in CIs. I am not sure this behavior is intuitive to me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the graph is showing the sample CATEs ordered from the lowest to the highest - i.e. the far left of the graph shows the sample member with the lowest estimated CATE. The label 'number of observations' is misleading - it's not to do with including more or less cases in the analysis, it's just the rank order of the CATE in the sample.

Essentially you can read off the range of variation in the estimated sample CATE's from the purple line, and the statistical uncertainty associated with the estimated CATE for each sample member from the blue lines.

It's not showing anything about the model's 'performance'.

Comment: Thank you for replying!  I really appreciate it. It makes sense that this is an ordered rank but I am not sure what it means. Does it mean that subjects with either very high/low CATE have more uncertaintly when we run inference on them? If so, why is that so?

Comment: In this example, yes, it does imply that very low/very high CATE's are estimated with a higher degree of uncertainty. I'm not familiar enough with causal forests to say definitively why, but I would guess that those estimates come from areas of the data that are relatively sparse - i.e. if you imagine that the CATEs might be ~normally distributed, the people in left/right tails are very unusual, and there's just not a lot of information about them.